# Response from GitHub API not returning an access token with appropriate scopes to view private repos

Tags: javascript, rest, api

I'm getting the response I want but the access token returned from GitHub returns with no scopes in the response:

```
// githubs response

{ 
  access_token: 'a2ed9606c8b06bf00a16dc34584b1509462450a4',
  token_type: 'bearer',
  scope: '' 
}
```

The token can't view private repos like my personal access token with the scopes enabled does. Am I doing something wrong or not contacting the correct endpoint?

```
// backend - Auth.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');

let token = null;

const createFetchOptions = (method, body = undefined) => {
    const options = {
        method,
        headers: {
            'Content-type': null,
            'Accept': null,
        },
    };

    options.headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json';
    options.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
    options.body = JSON.stringify(body);

    return options;
};

const Fetcher = {
    get: async (url) => {
        const res =
            await fetch(
                url,
                createFetchOptions('GET'),
            );
        return res;
    },

    post: async (url, body) => {
        const res =
            await fetch(
                url,
                createFetchOptions('POST', body),
            );
        return res;
    },
}

router.post('/token', async (req, res) => {
    const { clientId, clientSecret, sessionCode } = req.body;

    const response = await Fetcher.post('https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token', {
        client_id: clientId,
        client_secret: clientSecret,
        code: sessionCode,
    });

    const result = await response.json();
    console.log(result)
    res.json(result);
});


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your provided code seems to be missing the step where you [request the user's GitHub identity](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/#1-request-a-users-github-identity) by making a `GET https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize` request.  I'm assuming you do include this call somewhere in your code because it is necessary to receive the `sessionCode` value that you are passing in the body of your `POST https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token` request.

In any case, this is the step where you would specify [the various scopes](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/#available-scopes) that your application is requesting.  The requested scopes are passed via the `scope` query parameter, delimited by spaces if you are requesting multiple scopes.  For example, the following is a request for both the `user` and `public_repo` scopes:

```
GET https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?
  client_id=...&
  scope=user%20public_repo
```

Comment: Thank you im actually passing the result of a fetch to this endpoint when the react component did mount but you have pointed out something that i wasnt doing. I previously only had the client id not the scopes in the authorize get url. Will give it a shot and if it doesnt work will post that code as well

Comment: Sorry haven't had the time to try it out will update when i get to it at some point this week.

Comment: Really sorry about this only just got round to replying this seems to have done the trick was able to access much more than i was previously able to see. Thanks alot for the help :)